# Sum Of Limits Rule

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The rule states that given two function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $\lim f(x)=L$ and $\lim g(x)=M$ then $\lim f(x)+g(x)=L+M$

a. Is it true for the case that both $L=M=\infty$?

b. for a given limit to evaluate, can we assume, the two limit exists and to evaluate the two limits and then conclude on the limit of the sum?

Comment: We can distribute limit if  the limit of both functions exist and is finite, also for your second question, yes we should first determine both limits and if they exist and if the limits are finite the we can distribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following limit:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1}$$

Then we know :
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x}=\infty$$

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x+1}=\infty$$

So the wrong approach would be :
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x+1}=\infty+\infty=\infty$$

This is wrong , and gives us the wrong answer since we distribute limits, although we know they both **exist** but don't have a **finite** value.